# Given Set of Probabilities of Gaussian Distribution, How to Find Best Treshold and Maximum F1 Score?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

This problem related to the last programming exercise in [Andrew Ng's Course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/welcome). The objective of exercise is build a recommender system by implementing gaussian distribution algorithm. I have done that exercise, but I still not fully understand the algorithm to find best threshold.

To be honest, since I do not have appropriate mathematical skill, I provided some symbolic notations and its graphical visualization. Hope this formulation make sense:

Let:

$Q = \{x\ \mid x \in \{0, 1\}\}$

$R = \{x\ \mid x \in \mathbb{R},\ 0 < x < 1  \}$

$S = (a_i)_{i=1}^{n} \mid R_{min} \leq a \geq R_{max}$

Constrains:

$\{R \implies Q\}$: Each probability $R_i$ has binary value $Qi$

$S$ is arithmetic series $\{R_{min}$, ..., $R_{max}\}$ with predefined range $b$.

Solve:

$F_{max}$ while minimize $S_i$

The formulation of $F$ described in an image below:

[visual representation and formulation of F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuIN5.png)